# VBA to find column by name and reference values need to update if it nore than certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro contains couple of column values need to get update when we click the button.

```
Sub replaceBlank()
    Dim rng As Range
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
    For Each rng In Selection
        If rng = "" Or rng = " " Then
            rng.Value = "0"
        Else
        End If
     Next rng
End Sub
```

With this sample code I can only select the columns and execute. Instead, is there any possibility to change with list of column names then can we execute?

[image]

Comment: You can change the data to a table and then reference the `ListObject`

Comment: Or create a `Range` object referencing the specific columns and execute a `Range.Replace` method.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if you want to create the table programmatically. But for now we will proceed with the manual technique.

I'm using Excel 2016...First select the entire data set. Go to the [Insert] menu and select [Table]. Click anywhere inside the new table and the [Table Tools -> Design] menu will appear at the end of the ribbon. Go in there and take note of the [Table Name] field as you will need it in the code below to properly set the objList variable.

The column names are hard coded to an array but you can load a Listbox with column names  a hidden sheet and get really fancy with it if you like:

```
    Sub replaceBlank()

    Dim rngRow As Range, rngColDataSet As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objListCols As ListColumns
    Dim objList As ListObject

    Dim cntCols As Long, y As Long, MaxCols As Long
    Dim arColNames(1) As String

    'add column names as needed
    arColNames(0) = "Revenue"
    arColNames(1) = "Margin"

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'because ActiveSheet won't list properties/methods and that just bugs me
    Set objList = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set objListCols = objList.ListColumns

    MaxCols = objListCols.Count

    '--> loop each column in the table
    For cntCols = 1 To MaxCols
        '--> test if column is in the names you want processed
        For y = LBound(arColNames) To UBound(arColNames)
            If arColNames(y) = objListCols(cntCols).Name Then
                Set rngColDataSet = objListCols(cntCols).DataBodyRange.Areas(1)
    '-----------> OPTION 1: QUICK AND EFFICIENT!
                 rngColDataSet.Replace "", "0", xlWhole
                 rngColDataSet.Replace " ", "0", xlWhole
    '-----------> OPTION 2: IF YOU WANT TO ACCESS INDIVIDUAL CELL PROPERTIES OR METHODS <-------------------
    '            For Each rngRow In rngColDataSet
    '                If rngRow.Value = "" Or rngRow.Value = " " Then
    '                    rngRow.Value = "0"
    '                End If
    '            Next
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks to @Zack E and @JvdV for the inspiration ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @logicworkz . What if need to check whether the value is grater than some numeric value in the column value. How we can handle that?

Comment: Then use option 2 but instead of checking rngRow.Value for blanks, do rngRow.value > 10 or whatever value you want.

Comment: Is there any option to delete the entire row based on the column value matches the criteria ?! – @logicworkz

Comment: Rows(rngRow.Row).Delete